# List comprehension for finding a string in list?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a small challenge I want to manage - if possible - with list comprehension.

Example:

```
all_words = ["dongtestdong", "hello", "i", "am", "dongtest2dong", "like", "to", 
             "make", "dongtest3dong", "dance", "tonight" "do"]
split_list = ["test", "test2", "test3"]
```

Now what I want to do is - everytime I find a string in all_words, that matches any string in split_list, I want to get the "test" string and the next 2 strings in the all_words  string.

So in the example above the new string would be:

```
new_string = ["dongtestdong", "hello", "i", "dongtest2dong", "like", "to", 
              "dongtest3dong", "dance", "tonight"]
```

Comment: can you share what you have tried?

Comment: Updated the original

Comment: Why the specific requirement of using a list comprehension for this?

Comment: @AmitNanaware I made it just with a for word in all_words and then add them to the list if in the string, but I want to do with as less code as possible

Comment: @NPE want to do it with as less code as possible - if there is another very fast way outside of list comprehension I am open for this also, but I guessed it would be lowest amount of code

Comment: @DominikLemberger: To be honest, this sounds like premature optimization.  I'm also hearing some assumptions that are not necessarily justified (that list comprehensions equal "fast", that "fast" equals "least amount of code").

Comment: There are some corner cases here that was not mentioned. Like what if the list is like the one here `["dongtestdong", "dongtest2dong"]`. The words with test follow immediately.

Comment: I know that list comprehensions are not the fastest way, but time doesnt really matter in this case.

Comment: @Praveenkumar as soon as one of the strings in split_list is within one of the words in all_words it should take the whole word + the following 2. In this case for dongtestdong it should take the word + the 2 following hello and i, because test was found in dongtestdong

Comment: first create code without list comprehension and later you can try to rewrite it as list comprehension.

Comment: I did furas - without the list comprehension it works, but didnt know how to phrase / write it so it works within a list comprehension - have chosen the answer, as it works for me as intended

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one non-optimized list-comprehension :

```
new_list = [item for sublist in set([tuple(all_words[i:i+3]) for i,j in enumerate(all_words) for k in split_list if k in j]) for item in sublist]
```

**Output** :

```
["dongtestdong", "hello", "i", "dongtest2dong", "like", "to", "dongtest3dong", "dance", "tonight"]
```

Comment: Thanks exactly what I was looking for - will look if I can optimize it somehow

Answer (score 0):

```py
from functools import reduce

result = [all_words[ind:ind+3] for ind, x in enumerate(all_words) if any(y in x for y in split_list)]

#flatten your list if wanted
result = list(reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, result))
```